# Why are my NSURLConnection delegation methods not called?

Tags: xcode, multithreading, nsurlconnection, delegation

I've done exactly what [this official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) instructed. I created a console project for testing purpose. And then I created a class called RequestSender (see code below) and I made an instance of this class in the main function.

RequestSender.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface RequestSender : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDelegate> {
    NSMutableData* d;
}
@end
```

RequestSender.m:

```
#import "RequestSender.h"

@implementation RequestSender

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSString* s = @"http://www.apple.com/";
        NSURL* u = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:s];
        NSURLRequest* r = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:u];
        NSURLConnection* c = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:r delegate:self];
        if (c) {
            d = [NSMutableData data];
        }

        return self;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [d setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [d appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
}


@end
```

This will no doubt be executed in the main thread and default run loop. However non of the delegation methods are called.

I've done a lot of testing and read many posts but I still don't have a clue.

Please help me. This is driving me mad.
Thanx!

Comment: Your code looks okay. How do you call it? How is it embedded in your app?

Comment: Your code is absolutely right. Check self is null or not?

Comment: @Code : It's not in my app yet. I created a console project to test it. all the files are listed above. The only extra code is in the main function, which goes like "RequestSender* rs = [[RequestSender alloc] init];". I added breakpoints on every delegation methods, but none was captured.

Comment: @PrasadG : Do you think it has something to do with my using the console project?

Comment: @ Jack Jiang: Yes. If self is nil then there is no way to call the delegate methods.

Comment: 1) Are you sure your init function is called?  NSLog() and/or add break points.  2) Check your NSURLConnection init returns an object - if it doesn't none of the callbacks will be called (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the part where you *start* the connection. The connection class offers another method for this, or you could just call it off of your "c" object.

```
NSURLConnection* c = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:r delegate:self];
if (c) {
    d = [NSMutableData data];
    [c start];
}
```

or

```
NSURLConnection* c = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:r delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
if (c) {
    d = [NSMutableData data];
}
```

Comment: Also, wow -- didn't realize this question was that old. I hope you were able to fix it and aren't still waiting for an answer!